# How do i embed a custom font in CSS?

Tags: html, css, embed, font-face

I have recently been trying to embed font to my website. I don't get it to work, i have watched and read tutorials. I wan't to embed a font called "Ubuntu Light" in *ttf* format. This is what i have been trying:

```
#logBtn{
  font-family: 'UbuntuLight';
}
@font-face{
font-family: "UbuntuLight";
src: url("CSS/Ubuntu-L.ttf");
}
```

And the file in the folder: [Treeview of project](https://gyazo.com/e7e15bceedb54e524aa2b181d65118d7)

I'm almost new to this, i've been coding HTML and CSS in maybe 4 months now. 
I have been stuck at this before, and that made me cancel my project, because i gave up. But i don't want to give up again. So i would really appreciate some help! :)

Comment: I really recommend using https://www.google.com/fonts/ This includes the font you currently need and thousands of others, I've not looked but it it because you're importing the font AFTER it being used? - Also try removing the single-apostrophe

Comment: Did you convert the font via a webfont generator such as https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator before adding it to your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed a font quick and easy by using this code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Name';
  src: url('Font.ext');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Where Font.ext should be replaced with your font file and its extention (file type) e.g.

> src: url('Ubuntu-L.ttf');

And the following ***font-weight*** and ***font-style*** should be referencing the specific font choice.

Comment: But, it does not work. Could you please see what i have done wrong?    This is the **code**:                                                                                  `#logBtn{
  font-family: "UbuntuL";
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'UbuntuL';
  src: url('UbuntuL.ttf');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: Light;
}`                                                                                                               Maybe easier to see here: https://i.gyazo.com/f1d365053f57ade7476bb886b1f34b86.png

Comment: Your font-face declaration should always be at the top of your CSS file, @SynomousArtz

Answer (score 0):

The `url(...)` path is relative to the stylesheet.

Therefore, because your stylesheet is in the `CSS` folder you don't need to include that in the url:

```
@font-face{
  font-family: "UbuntuLight";
  src: url("Ubuntu-L.ttf");
}
```